# Turn string to array in PHP (all data recorder as string)

Tags: php, oop, multidimensional-array

I want to have a multidim. array like this:

```
array {[RECORD1] => array {
                      [ID]=>"0001",
                      [Name]=>"John",
                      [Address]=>"Street No...."
                     }
[RECORD2] => array {
                      [ID]=>"0002",
                      [Name]=>"Jane",
                      [Address]=>"Street No...."
                     }
      }
```

I managed to create a code like this:

```
$st = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE c_id=?");
$au='array(';
    foreach ($_SESSION['cid'] as $cr){
        $st->execute(array($cr));
        $rws = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($rws as $rw){}
        $au.='"a'.$cr.'"=>array('; //Record01
        $au.='"id"=>"'.$rw['c_id'].'",';
        $au.='"name"=>"'.$rw['c_name'].'"';
        $au.='),';

    }
    $au=trim($au,',');
    //substr($au,0,-1);
$au.=');';
```

the result is a string, but with content of an array.

Second question: is it better to use OOP to do what I want?

**What I need:** After I select some "records" (which can be removed/added later-on), I will integrate them in a comparison page. This array/class should be flexible enough so I can easily alter it (when adding/removing records).
I thought using arrays I can easily remove/add a "record".

Thank you.

Comment: What are you actually asking? PHP supports multi dimensional arrays out of the box. As for your code, I have to wonder what you're trying to do and how you came to this solution....

Comment: Perhaps the answer is simply to point you at the [array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: What you currently create are not arrays at all. It is a string, not more, not less. Just because it has the word "array" in it does not somehow make it an array.

Comment: Did you notice that the loop `foreach ($rws as $rw){}` immediately ends? `$rw` will never be valid.

Comment: @arkascha I agree with you. the question is: can I turn this string to an array, or what can I do?

Comment: No you can't, at least that does not make any sense. Instead of creating a string you should create an array. That's all the secret.

Comment: @Vaia believe it or not, I works, even though I know it's not a proper solution. please advise is you have a better one. :) The fact is that it generates the loop (creating the needed array with all the data, meaning $rw[...])

Comment: Okay, time to stop coding. Please read documentation and tutorials before going _any_ further. It seems clear that at least when it comes to PHP you don't know / understand what your doing and are practically hitting random keys and hoping things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have one cid in `$_SESSION['cid']` you might use;

```
$sSQL = 'SELECT c_id, c_name, c_address FROM table WHERE c_id=:c_id';
$st = $conn->prepare($sSQL);
$st->bindValue( 'c_id', $_SESSION['cid'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();

// create results array
$aResults = array();

// while there are rows to get, loop over and store results in array
while($row = $st->fetch()){
  $aResults[$row['c_id']] = array('Name'=>$row['c_name'], 'Address'=>$row['c_address']);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your support, unlike others! This looks like the proper approach for me. Yes, I noticed the thing I did wrong: it is only possible to put variables into an array, but never the whole "string" as variable.

Comment: No problem at all. Yeah you where creating what you visually see as the array structure as a string. Still impressed you managed that. Have a read up on data types, and how php handles them for things like storage, comparison etc.